# What is causing Missing $ inserted error?

Tags: tables, compilation-error

I created a table using latex-tables.com, and I used overleaf to quickly make minor adjustments until the table looked exactly as I wanted. Everything compiles without error on overleaf. However, my local compiler seems to have trouble compiling the code, and I just cannot figure it out. It just stops at `! Missing $ inserted`. And I cannot figure out where the error is coming from. Below is a picture of the table compiled in Overleaf, followed by an MWE with the problem.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \resizebox{200}{!}{
        \refstepcounter{table}
        \label{tab:my-table}
        \arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.271,0.271,0.275}
        \ADLnullwidehline
        \begin{tabular}{!{\color{black}\vrule}lr!{\color{black}\vrule}rl}
            \multicolumn{1}{!{\color{black}\vrule}c}{push} & \multicolumn{1}{c!{\color{black}\vrule}}{pop} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Function} \\ 
            \cdashline{1-2}
            \multicolumn{1}{!{\color{black}\vrule}c}{\downarrow} & \multicolumn{1}{c!{\color{black}\vrule}}{\uparrow} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{ call no.} \\ 
            \arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}\cline{1-2}
            x = & \textbf{0} & \multirow{2}{*}{\huge\}} & \multirow{2}{*}{5} \\ 
        \arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.271,0.271,0.275}\cdashline{1-2}
        return & \textbf{1} &  &  \\ 
        \cline{1-2}
        x = & \textbf{1} & \multirow{2}{*}{\huge\}} & \multirow{2}{*}{4} \\ 
        \cdashline{1-2}
        return & \textbf{1} &  &  \\ 
        \cline{1-2}
        x = & \textbf{1} & \multirow{2}{*}{\huge\}} & \multirow{2}{*}{3} \\ 
        \cdashline{1-2}
        return & \textbf{2} &  &  \\ 
        \cline{1-2}
        x = & \textbf{3} & \multirow{2}{*}{\huge\}} & \multirow{2}{*}{2} \\ 
        \cdashline{1-2}
        return & \textbf{6} &  &  \\ 
        \cline{1-2}
        x = & \textbf{4} & \multirow{2}{*}{\huge\}} & \multirow{2}{*}{1} \\ 
        \cdashline{1-2}
        return & \textbf{24} &  &  \\
        \arrayrulecolor{black}\cline{1-2}
        \end{tabular}
        }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

In case it matters, here is the version information for my install of pdflatex:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)
kpathsea version 6.3.2
Copyright 2020 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
```

Comment: You can't use `\downarrow` or `\uparrow` outside of math mode. To myke sour code compilable, you can use `\(\downarrow\)` and `\(\uparrow\)`.

Comment: Additionally, the second argument of `\resizebox` is missing its unit, thus the error message " Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).". However, I recommend to not use `\resizebox` on a table as it will lead to inconsistent font sizes.

Comment: Using ```\(downarrow\)``` still gives the same error. I removed the ```\resizebox``` also.

Comment: Just to make sure: did you use `\(downarrow\)` or `\(\downarrow\)`? The latter would be correct. Also, did you surround `\downarrow` and `\uparrow` in a set of `\(`, `\)` or just one of them?

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo in my comment. I did use the correct version: ```\(\downarrow\)```. And I surrounded both in a set of ```\(```,```\)```.

Comment: @leandriis, I made your suggested changes in Overleaf (which complained in their logs about the same error, but still rendered the pdf correctly, weird) and then I copied that into my document and everything worked. Thanks.

Comment: "compiles without error on overleaf" and "rendered the pdf correctly" are two different things.  Overleaf will tell you about the errors; it just makes it a bit harder to find.  But if there are errors, the output is just TeX's best guess at what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer. Just a compilation of above comments to close this question.
Please do not vote.

This code works properly:

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
        \refstepcounter{table}
        \label{tab:my-table}
        \arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.271,0.271,0.275}
        \ADLnullwidehline
        \begin{tabular}{!{\color{black}\vrule}lr!{\color{black}\vrule}rl}
            \multicolumn{1}{!{\color{black}\vrule}c}{push} & \multicolumn{1}{c!{\color{black}\vrule}}{pop} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Function} \\ 
            \cdashline{1-2}
         \multicolumn{1}{!{\color{black}\vrule}c}{\(\downarrow\)} & \multicolumn{1}{c!{\color{black}\vrule}}{\(\uparrow\)} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{ call no.} \\ 
            \arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}\cline{1-2}
            x = & \textbf{0} & \multirow{2}{*}{\huge\}} & \multirow{2}{*}{5} \\ 
        \arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.271,0.271,0.275}\cdashline{1-2}
        return & \textbf{1} &  &  \\ 
        \cline{1-2}
        x = & \textbf{1} & \multirow{2}{*}{\huge\}} & \multirow{2}{*}{4} \\ 
        \cdashline{1-2}
        return & \textbf{1} &  &  \\ 
        \cline{1-2}
        x = & \textbf{1} & \multirow{2}{*}{\huge\}} & \multirow{2}{*}{3} \\ 
        \cdashline{1-2}
        return & \textbf{2} &  &  \\ 
        \cline{1-2}
        x = & \textbf{3} & \multirow{2}{*}{\huge\}} & \multirow{2}{*}{2} \\ 
        \cdashline{1-2}
        return & \textbf{6} &  &  \\ 
        \cline{1-2}
        x = & \textbf{4} & \multirow{2}{*}{\huge\}} & \multirow{2}{*}{1} \\ 
        \cdashline{1-2}
        return & \textbf{24} &  &  \\
        \arrayrulecolor{black}\cline{1-2}
        \end{tabular}    
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: final]

Answer (score 2):

I propose a simpler code for this table, with  `bigdelim` (which comes with `multirow`):

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{multirow, bigdelim, makecell}
    \usepackage{colortbl}
    \usepackage{arydshln}
    \usepackage{graphics}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \centering
            \begin{tabular}{!{\color{black}\vrule}l>{\bfseries}r!{\color{black}\vrule}l}
                \multicolumn{1}{!{\color{black}\vrule}c}{push} & \multicolumn{1}{c!{\color{black}\vrule}}{pop} & \multirowcell{2}{Function\\call no} \\
                \cdashline{1-2}
                \multicolumn{1}{!{\color{black}\vrule}c}{$\downarrow $} & \multicolumn{1}{c!{\color{black}\vrule}}{$ \uparrow $} & \\
                \arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}\cline{1-2}
                x = & 0 & \rdelim \}{2}{*}[\quad 5] \\
                \arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.271,0.271,0.275}\cdashline{1-2}
                return & 1 \\
                \cline{1-2}
                x = & 1 & \rdelim \}{2}{*}[\quad 4] \\
                \cdashline{1-2}
                return & 1 \\
                \cline{1-2}
                x = & 1 & \rdelim \}{2}{*}[\quad 3] \\
                \cdashline{1-2}
                return & \textbf{2} \\
                \cline{1-2}
                x = & 3 & \rdelim \}{2}{*}[\quad 2] \\
                \cdashline{1-2}
                return & 6 \\
                \cline{1-2}
                x = & 4 &\rdelim\}{2}{*}[\quad 1] \\
                \cdashline{1-2}
                return & 24 \\
                \arrayrulecolor{black}\cline{1-2}
            \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]